# Preserving the links between files when exporting multiple powerpoint files to PDF files

Tags: pdf, microsoft-powerpoint, export, hyperlink

I have a presentation with many rich slides (about 150) and many internal links to navigate between the slides. The internal links are preserved when exporting the file to PDF (I provide the presentation in PDF, not in PPTX).

The problem is that Powerpoint tend to be unresponsive (mainly when saving or autosaving, it can take 10 seconds) as this presentation gets bigger and bigger. So I'd like to split it into several smaller files. I can edit the links when needed to transform them to crosslinks (from one file to another), but the cross-links are broken once the files are exported to PDF: they point to the original PPTX files and not to the PDF files...

Question: is there a way to have the crosslinks automatically updated to point to the PDF files (and ideally to point to specific slides of the files)? This somehow assumes that the Powerpoint export function has the ability to process several PPTX files as a group, and I can't see such a feature. Optionally, a single final PDF file would be OK, as large PDF file are not a problem.

Comment: This'd be possible if you're fairly skillful at writing VBA, but it's not a beginner project. Also, IIRC, there used to be a way to have PDFs open to a specific page, but only when they're served from a web site, not locally. I don't know whether that's changed or not. Personally, I'd turn off AutoSaves, store the file locally rather than in the cloud and live with the occasional slow save. Or break the file up into chunks while you create most of the slides, bring them back together into one big file, create the links and then export to PDF.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg OK, I will live with the unresponsiveness, then, and possibly deactivating autosaves.